# Is it possible to Derive class from CWinThread Class in dialog based application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am working with Dialog based application.
My Question is that, I want to show Waiting dialog, until some database operation carried out.
i Used Derived class from CWinThread, but problem is that, when this thread close, the background (Main application dialog) remains at deactivated means( it hide behind another window). 
i am thinking that, this is happening because of WaitDialog used CWinThread class.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not unique to a dialog based application. Creating windows of any kind in more than one thread is difficult and not recommended. In your case it sounds like your wait dialog is modal, while its parent dialog is in another thread. That is even worse and can lead to deadlocks between threads.

The reliable solution is to put the wait dialog (and all other GUI) in the main thread, and the lengthy database processing in a secondary thread.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use a [Modeless Dialogbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#modeless_box) which can also optionally show the status and call the [DestroyWindow function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when the database operation is completed -- you may need to disable some operations of the main window while the Modeless Dialogbox is visible, though.

Comment: which option can you tell me.. because, i had used model less dialog box before, implementing class which derived from CWinThread but problem is, if we click on main dialog while in processing, it showing not responding at crash the application with giving option, either wait or close application.

Comment: you will need to set up a HWND variable (either a global variable or a member variable in your CDialog-derived class) to the HWND of the modeless dialog and prevent the users from clicking on buttons in the main dialog if this HWND is not NULL

Comment: I tried your suggested approach which ask for model less dialog, i also restrict all button click, it work fine, until the few millisecond remaining for background processing done, it crashed if we click on anywhere(main dialog or wait dialog) while just some millisecond is remaining for all background processed finished.

Comment: are you waiting for the background thread to complete before destroying the modeless dialog box?

Comment: yes, after finished processing, i Destroy modelless dialog box and assign null to the Window handle which is used in clicking.

Comment: then I don't understand where these "milliseconds" come in -- where is the crash? does the main dialog still "know" that the background has not completed?

Comment: let me ask in details, i want to take record from database and write that record in file, until this operation is finished i want to show waiting dialog so that, disturbance or any unwanted processing do not proceed, until db operation finished. i did all most crate model less dialog, show that dialog, and call other class function which read data form db and write it into file, but i notice that, when db processing started, the main dialog application shows like(not responding) and mouse cursor changes to wait state, and same time if we clicked on main dialog or on wait dialog, it crashed.

Comment: where is the crash? could it be that the main dialog box is using variables which are also used by the thread?

Comment: No, its crashed when background processing is proceeding, and at same time if we click on main dialog or wait dialog.

Comment: No, its crashed when background processing is proceeding, and at same time if we click on main dialog or wait dialog. might be this happening because of application gets idle while in background processing, and we are trying to do something while in app is busy. actually my requirement is unique, but i have to do something with old code, i cant change all code. ask me one thing, what can we do, if application goes to idle state means. mouse cursor goes to wait state.if i get this then i can solve this problem. i noticed, that in processing it will take goes to idle even modeless dialog is used

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on my previous answer, it looks like that alternative is not viable in this situation.

Maybe a better way would be to create a normal modal "wait" dialog box, start the background thread in the dialog's InitDialog, periodically check the status of the thread using a timer and end the dialog when the thread completes?